# DropDownList e ListBox - Recuperando Valores na Edição

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Em um **CMS** possuo uma `DropDownList` e um `ListBox` que funcionam regularmente no campo de cadastro, porém, não trazem valores no campo de edição.

View

```
<div>
    Tipo de Curso<br />
    @Html.DropDownList("TipoCurso", ViewData["listTipoCurso"] as SelectList)
</div>

<div>
    Promoções <br /> 
    @Html.ListBox("Promocoes", 
        new MultiSelectList(ViewData["Promocoes"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable, 
        "id", "nome"), new 
        { 
            @class = "chosen-select", 
            @placeholder = "Escolha uma Opção" 
        })
</div>
```

Controller

```cs
TipoCursoAplicacao bdTipoCurso;
bdTipoCurso = TipoCursoAplicacaoConstrutor.TipoCursoAplicacaoEF();
var listTipoCurso = new SelectList(bdTipoCurso.ListarTodos()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Nome.ToLower().Trim()).Select(y => y.First()), 
    "ID", "Nome");
ViewData["listTipoCurso"] = listTipoCurso;

PromocoesAplicacao bdPromocoes;
bdPromocoes = PromocoesAplicacaoConstrutor.PromocoesAplicacaoEF();
ViewData["Promocoes"] = bdPromocoes.ListarTodos();
```

Como poderia proceder para trazer selecionados os dados cadastrados na **Listbox** e no **DropDownLis**t na hora da edição?

Comment: O problema é que TipoCurso e Promocoes são chaves estrangeiras e a minha View está tipada para Cursos

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido graças a ajuda que recebi nos comentários.

View

```
<div>
    Tipo de Curso <br /> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TipoCurso.ID, ViewData["listTipoCurso"] as SelectList)
</div>
```

Controller

```
TipoCursoAplicacao bdTipoCurso;
bdTipoCurso = TipoCursoAplicacaoConstrutor.TipoCursoAplicacaoEF();
Cursos.TipoCurso = bdTipoCurso.ListarPorId(collection["TipoCurso.ID"]);
```